# Can not assign var i = window.location.href

Tags: window.location

Somehow I can not assign

```
var i = window.location.href;
```

While this work

```
console.log(window.location.href);
```

I am using JQuery 3.3.1

Comment: That is highly unlikely `var i = window.location.href;
console.log(i)` - your code has NO jQuery in it. Please show more code in a [mcve]

Comment: works pretty well https://jsfiddle.net/4tsvhL7z/

Comment: Ok, late to reply back. though accepted answer works but still if I use 'var'. It says undefined. But I solved it without using any extra variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must works.

```js
i = window.location.href

document.write( i )
```

Comment: The console is giving the message `undefined` but the var actually isn't. It is just telling that the console has nothing to display as output. You can use `var` or `let` as well here.